# How to import OS street view data into MapInfo Pro

Tags: mapinfo, ordnance-survey

I'm trying to import multiple files into MapInfo Pro to create one tab file which is a map background of my local authority.

I'm not a regular user of MapInfo and my skills are at a beginners level. The files downloaded from Ordnance Survey contain Tab files in a georeferencing folder, jpegs in a data folder and tiff files in a data folder.

I have moved the tab files and jpegs into one folder together and I am able to view my map background. The layers are all fitting together and are geographically where they should be.

At this point, the layers are not editable or selectable. I did try saving a copy and opening that tab file but it remains unselectable and uneditable which means many of the menu options are unavailable to me.

I would like to know how I can combine all of these layers to make one tab file?

Comment: I am also not able to download extra software to my work computer to assist with this.

Comment: For OS Street View you can download the geo-referenceing tab (for Mapinfo) files from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/geo-referencing-files/os-streetview-tab-georeferencing-files.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MapInfo has a tool called seamless table manager, which you can load by going to the tools menu then choosing tool manager. Scroll down and tick the box to load the tool (and put one in the box to autoload it if you are likely to use it in future sessions). 
The tool allows you to create a single tab file to load multiple raster tiles. Open all your Street View tiles in to the same map window, then go to the tools menu and choose Seamless Manager ->New Seamless Table. MapInfo will prompt you where to save your file.

Comment: Should have said the above works in MapInfo v12.5

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded and added the [raster](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/opendata-getting-started.html) version of OS Street View which is usually used for background maps.

If you want to select, edit or otherwise mutilate the data you need to download the (bigger) [vector](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/opendata-getting-started.html) version of one of the other OS products such as OS Open Map - Local.

P.S. OS Could you add link anchors to the product page so people can link to a specific download?

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html   . It is the street view file I downloaded. I just need a background map that I can use as a base for other maps or for loading our school route network on top of. My problem is that the map is split into tiles and I would like one big map of the relevant tiles. I can see that in the past someone has created a background of our county and it is regularly used for map backgrounds I wanted to create something similar as the map background is now out of date. Would it be possible to do this with the version i have downloaded?

Comment: If you edit your question to include this information someone who uses MapInfo may be able to help you, I know how to do it in QGIS

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/geo-referencing-files/os-streetview-tab-georeferencing-files.zip